# Django rest ModelViewSet methods missing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    stakeholders = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null = True, )
```

A serializer:

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'projects', ProjectViewSet)


urlpatterns = router.urls
```

And a view:

```
class ProjectViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

I am expecting my ModelViewSet to provide me CRUD operations on Project model, I am using drf docs and what I see is following:

[image]

all the methods are basically missing, and I am not sure what that extra /api/ endpoint is?

Comment: What is `DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES` in `settings.py`? Probably you set it to `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly` and doc shows you only safe methods?

Comment: I just checked, I do not have it at all my settings.py. What should I set it to?

Comment: By default it's `AllowAny`. Check details here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#setting-the-permission-policy

Comment: AllowAny didn't help. I have two apps in my project, one app is using views with @api_view(['GET']) and defs and this one I was trying with ModelViewSet. Could that create a problem? Also the first app uses urlpatterns = [] format

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure what that extra /api/ endpoint is?

From the docs:

> This (DefaultRouter) router is similar to SimpleRouter as above, but additionally includes a default API root view, that returns a response containing hyperlinks to all the list views.

I don't use `DRF Docs`, but looks like it doesn't support `ModelViewSet` for now (read the discussion https://github.com/manosim/django-rest-framework-docs/issues/58 for details). Make a direct call to endpoint to make sure it works or not.